# git lfs migration and pulling from upstream

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am pulling code from an upstream server (Github) and making changes to the code locally and pushing to a downstream server (Gitlab). Others I work with will pull/push with the Gitlab server.

Now because of large files, we then have to use git-lfs on the Gitlab server. We have performed the migrate to change all existing large files to lfs files. I can see this rewrites history and now it looks like there are 2 branches which contain all the same commit contents but with different commit IDs.

I hope to have one history but how can I deal with the upstream server having the 'old' history and my lfs files having the 'new' history? When it comes to merging will this just be a total nightmare? I will not be pushing code upstream to Github, so I cannot change the upstream files to lfs files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does git lfs reduce the size of files pushed to Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922231/does-git-lfs-reduce-the-size-of-files-pushed-to-github)

Comment: @Christoph It doesn't seem to address the issue I have. My problem isn't about the storage of lfs files, it is about how I can deal with non-lfs files upstream and lfs files downstream and also having 2 histories.

Comment: Any why not migrate your history as suggested in the question?