# Why did a small commit cause git bare repo to double in size?

Tags: git, git-bare

I created a clean git bare repo and pushed around 300MB of files to it (on the master branch). At this point, the git bare repo was 57MB in size. I then changed 10 files, 9 were small ~1KB source files and 1 was a 900K binary file. I committed these changes to another branch (dev_branch) and pushed to the bare repo. After this, my bare repo size is now 114MB (doubled in size from a fairly small commit). I'm doing this in a local test, nobody else has access, so the bare repo only has these 2 commits (on 2 different branches).

I was thinking only the changes would be stored and the bare repo size would barely grow from such a small commit, maybe the size of the files max (~1-2MB). Why did such a small commit cause the bare repo to double in size?

Comment: What kind of files are they? Are they binaries?

Comment: Most of them are source code text files (some of those are MBs in size). There are some binaries, around 30-50. No single file is larger than 20MB

Comment: Sounds like you think that git store the diff between commits? That's not how git works. It saves whole files at a time..... it will avoid saving the same content twice..... doesn't matter if it's in different commits with different names.... _but_ they are saved **in full**.

Comment: "I was thinking only the changes would be stored" Nope. A commit is a snapshot of your entire project. No "changes" are involved. Git can save space by occasionally "packing" a batch of commits but that's not a requirement. Permit me to recommend my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ It will rid you of your misconceptions.

Comment: Consider using git-lfs?

Comment: Ah, there's the nugget I didn't know -- that git stores a snapshot with every commit. If one of you want to add that as the answer, I'll check it off. Does git-lfs cause the bare repo size to be smaller? How does it store them differently to do that?

Comment: It can take Git a while to notice dupllicates that arrived in separate pushes to separate branches. Try a repack on the bare repo, `git repack -ad`, it'd eventually get around to doing that itself anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A commit in Git: Is it a snapshot/state/image or is it a change/diff/patch/delta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617288/a-commit-in-git-is-it-a-snapshot-state-image-or-is-it-a-change-diff-patch-delta)

Comment: I ran the `git repack -ad` command and the bare repo returned to size 57MB, so it does look like it removed duplicates (parts that weren't changed in further commits) as I originally expected. I also setup a separate bare repo using git-lfs and using the exact same commits and branches. That bare repo was 185MB after the first commit, and stayed 185MB at the second. In these tests, it looks like git-lfs is worse for this case, though I don't know why. Since I'm not planning on the binary files changing much, I'm unsure if it's better or worse to use git-lfs in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was waiting for a commenter to post their answer as an answer, but I'll go ahead since they haven't.

The short answer (thanks to several people in the comments) is that git stores a complete snapshot for every commit, which explains the double size from the 2nd commit of a small change set. It doesn't stay this way though, as commits go on, git does do a lot of work to pack everything, including using blobs to store file contents in a way that duplicate files can point to the same blob instead of storing the blob twice. For my small example, I thought it would do this on the push, but that appears to not always be the case. I was able to run `git repack -ad` to return the size of the 2-commit repo to 57MB (about the same size of the 1-commit repo).

Comment: Additionally, I found this answer helpful in understanding git-lfs to guide in figuring out whether or not my smaller "large" files will be worth the trade-offs git-lfs provides: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73707142/4195988